# Template engine design question?

Tags: mvc, templates

I don't know if this is the proper forum for the question as any answers will be rather subjective. But here it goes, please advise if there is a better place to ask this.

I am designing a small template engine for a very small MVC framework in PHP. Right now, the views take in an array from the controller that can be displayed with [variable]. Besides that, the view will read @extends[layout] for the actual "master page", and @section which will read a block ending in @endsection or a single line @section[key=value]. Either of those are read by @render in the master template.

I know other templating engines allow for some pretty advanced logic, and I have seen those misused.

In summary, these are the commands allowed (recognized) in my view class:

```
@extends[path/to/layout]
@section[key=value]
@section[key]
    value
    value...
@endsection[key]
```

the master template (layout) reads

```
@render[value of block or key]
```

also

```
[varvalue]
```

varvalue is sent from the controller as part of an array (it is very similar to how Laravel and Django deal with controllers and views).

My question is this; I am trying to enforce an actual MVC design pattern and force most of the logic to be placed in the controller. What are the minimum required commands that I should allow in the view? My thought so far is to provide for a basic loop and a basic if.

Is there something I am not considering?

Comment: Can you elaborate what restrictions you want to place on a View in your MVC framework. Technically, the View can vary from a static HTML template with only simple substitutions to the javascript frontend of an SPA application.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I figure that if you are developing a single page app, you are not going to choose an MVC framework as your platform. As far as "restrictions", that is basically my question. My personal design ethic is to handle all of the logic (at least as much as possible) in the controller. At the moment, my design employs simple substitution. Just curious what other think should be available in the view. As I said, I am not sure this is the proper forum as it is fairly subjective.